# Max value error message on number type input

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a number type input box in my form. I have set the min and max value for this. However i want to display a error message to the user when he enters more than the specified max value.

I have written the ng-show, but still the error message won't show up when the user enters more the max value

Below is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="maxvaluetest" id="maxvaluetest" ng-model="maxvaluetest" min="0" max="100" ng-change="record()" 
ng-required="showError">
<span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="myform.maxvaluetest.$dirty && myform.maxvaluetest.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myform.maxvaluetest.$error">{{myform.maxvaluetest.$error}}</span>
</span>
```

Am i missing something here?

Is there any alternative to display the error message? Am using Angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You need to use angulars version of min and max. I.E

```
ng-min="0" ng-max="100"
```

Also, I think the error that occurs will no longer be required, it will probably be.

```
myform.maxvaluetest.$error.max
```

If you put this in your HTML it will print out the version to use for your error message

```
{{myform.maxvaluetest.$error}}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. However am not getting any message displayed when the user enter more than the specified max value. I changed the min and max to angulars version as you have mentioned. Perhaps a sample code may help

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have edited my code above and have changed min and max to ng versions. To display the error message, i have added one more attribute ng-required. This variable (boolean) will be updated in my script when the user enters a value more than 100. The message displayed will be "{required":true, "number":false}. If i remove the attribute ng-required, then no error message will be displayed even if the entered value is more than 100. Any suggestion here?

Comment: Can you set it up on a JS Fiddle? Makes it a lot easier to debug for you

Comment: i had written the code in JSFiddle, but my controller is not getting called http://jsfiddle.net/JClouseau/8m93pm9s/ do i need to add anything in jsfiddle to call my controller?

Comment: Update: I have resolved the console error. Here is the new link: http://jsfiddle.net/JClouseau/8m93pm9s/8/. In the fiddle result, if the user enters a value more than 100, then in my controller, the entered value becomes 'undefined'. So the help block (error message) is never displayed to the user when the entered value is more than 100. Is it possible to display the error message in this case?

Comment: According to the docs there is no `ng-min` or `ng-max` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D